# Animate root view controller embedded into a navigation controller presented modally

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I need to animate a UIViewController which is the root of a UINavigationController. This navigation controller is presented modally.
I know I can do it with the lifecycle methods of the view controller, but I want to use a `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` if possible to keep the VC code clean.

I tried the following:

a) Set the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to the navigation controller, so I could use this delegate function:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
```

However, it only gets called during transitions within the navigation controller (from VC to VC).

b) Set a `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` in the root view controller and use this delegate function:

```
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
```

But again, it doesn't get called as the one presenting is the navigation controller.

c) Set a `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` in the navigation controller and use the same delegate function:

```
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
```

In this case, it gets called and I can inject the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` object, but I can only think about hacks to animate the root, e.g.

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
          let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) as? UINavigationController,
          toVC.children.count == 1,
          let myRootVC = toVC.children.first as? MyViewController
    else {
        transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
        return
    }
    // Animate manually
    myRootVC.view.alpha = 0
    // [...]
}
```

Do you know any way to capture this nicely?

Comment: have you come up with a solution? I'm also stuck on this

Answer (score 1):

I solved the similar problem by making all my `ViewControllers` being presented as embedded ViewControllers using ViewController Containment.

I do have 1 `RootContainerViewController` setup when launching the the application - it's simply set as `rootViewController` without animations and it's just container for all other ViewControllers.

All other ViewControllers are always added as SubViewControllers and SubViews to that container.

That allows you not only to use `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` for every single transition in your application, but also it allows you to easily make "reset" of the app, by just removing `RootContainerViewController` and replacing it with fresh one.
Another advantage is that you can add as many ViewControllers as you want - compared to native `presentViewController` that allows you to have only 1 ViewController presented at a time.

Any other approaches I tried ended up badly - `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` is impossible to use directly with `rootViewController` changes - you will have to combine it with `UIView.animate` to support it.

Comment: I think in that case I'd prefer to put the animation logic into the VC code and animate it. In my case it's a modally presented navigation controller, so I think I'd prefer this rather than  adding a root container and then transitioning from there. Thanks!

Comment: @jomafer once you will add more animations and then ever modify how viewcontrollers are connected - having own presentation system becomes handy ;)